# Cannot load Neo4jConfiguration with spring-data-neo4j 2.2.1

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to both Neo4j and Spring. I have tried to do my homework as well as I can - my most sincere apologies if there is a magical doc with all the answers I missed along the way.

The aim is to interact with a Neo4j database using spring-data-neo4j. I have followed the guide in Good Relationships to some success, but would like to move on from version 1.6.M02,  used in the book.

Although it is not [specified](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j/2.2.1.RELEASE) in the Maven repository for spring-data-neo4j 2.2.1, the version of Neo4j that is included by Maven is 1.8.1, which as far as I am aware is the correct version. This also pulls in the Spring framework (3.1.4) as it should. So `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>yet</groupId>
    <artifactId>another</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cinecopy</name>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So then we have the most simple test case possible:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:testContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    Neo4jTemplate template;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void badNews() {

        Person add = new Person();
        add.setName("What.");

        add = template.save(add);

    }

}
```

Which refers to `testContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/config-test"/>

</beans>
```

This gives me ([full trace](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=se8VZ25n)):

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext [...]
Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration
```

I find this peculiar given that things seem to work fine with `pom.xml` as:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>yet</groupId>
    <artifactId>another</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cinecopy</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.M02</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the newly released 2.3.0.M1 for compatibility with Neo4j 1.9

Comment: please make also sure you have cglib in your pom.xml (That's what it is complaining about)                  <dependency>
                        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.2</version>
                </dependency>

Comment: Thanks, Michael - I had seen it complaining about cglib earlier, but included 3.0. Works just smashing with 2.2 and 2.3.0.M1/1.9.

Thanks for all your work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, `pom.xml` after Michael's input (or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588917/standalone-spring-data-neo4j-2-2-0-release-hangs-instead-of-exits) - so much for claiming to have done my homework):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>another</groupId>
    <artifactId>cine</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>yetagain</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-validation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I did not, however, encounter the same "hanging" issue as Steve - but then so far all I've done is load ApplicationContext.